# Unable to parse XML with multiple namespaces using tcl and tdom

Tags: xml-parsing, tcl, tdom

I am trying to parse a XML using tcl and tdom package. I am having trouble doing this as the node I want to parse is a child to a node with multiple namespaces. How would I be able to parse the realmCode or title element? Below is what I have tried:

```
package require tdom

set XML {<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.cerner.com/cda_stylesheet/" ?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 ../../../CDA%20R2/cda-schemas-and-samples/infrastructure/cda/CDA.xsd" classCode="DOCCLIN" moodCode="EVN">
    <realmCode code="US" />
    <title>Discharge Summary</title>
</ClinicalDocument>}

set nsmap {
  a urn:hl7-org:v3
  x http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
  s urn:hl7-org:sdtc
}

set doc [dom parse $XML]
set root [$doc documentElement]
set node [$root selectNodes -namespaces $nsmap "/a:ClinicalDocument/title"]
#set node [$root selectNodes "/ClinicalDocument/title"] ;# tried this as well - does not work

$doc delete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace for *every* level of the path, not just the root. Use

```
set title [$root selectNodes -namespaces $nsmap /a:ClinicalDocument/a:title]
set realm [$root selectNodes -namespaces $nsmap /a:ClinicalDocument/a:realmCode/@code]
```

etc.

Comment: This is necessary because of the way XPath works with XML Namespaces (i.e., not very well).

Comment: A suggestion for improvement: Use `$doc selectNodesNamespaces $nsmap`, this will make the mapping available to all `selectNodes` calls.

Comment: @mrcalvin I don't know the library; just copied OP's code. That sounds handy though.

Answer (score 0):

This is more for the sake of completeness, and not necessarily recommended. You may instruct tDOM to simply ignore the namespaces. See [`-ignorexmlns`](http://www.tdom.org/index.html/doc/trunk/doc/dom.html).

Watch:

```
set doc [dom parse -ignorexmlns $XML]
set root [$doc documentElement]
$root selectNodes "/ClinicalDocument/title"
$root selectNodes "/ClinicalDocument/realmCode/@code"
```

The consequences are obvious: ambiguity.